# Why this predicate logic formula is written the way it is here?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have this sentence: "All parrots are black and there exist a parrot which is in the cage." It is probably written in a predicate logic like this:

$(\forall x) b(x)\land(\exists y) c(y)$

My question is: Why there has to be two variables (x and y) istead of one?

Comment: Variables that are quantified (i.e. in the scope of a quantifier) have no "life" outside of their "context", i.e. outside the sub-formula that is in the scope of the quantifier. Thus, you can re-use them in different context, but this does **not** mean that they refer to the "same object".

Comment: Than why can't I use only one variable in the following formula (which has the same meaning as the one above in my opinion)?: $(\forall x)(\exists y) (b(x)\land c(y))$ . Or can I write it this way as well?: $(\forall x)(\exists x) (b(x)\land c(x))$

Comment: @TKN logic no care of opinions

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee of course logic don't care of opinions. I meant to say - to my best knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that are in the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(logic)) of a quantifier have no "life" outside their context, i.e. outside the sub-formula that is the scope of the quantifier.

Thus, we can re-use a variable in different contexts [but this does not mean that it refers to the same object; consider e.g. $\exists x \ \text {Odd}(x) \land \exists x \ \text {Even}(x)$ ].

This means that the above formula is equivalent to: $(∀x)b(x) ∧ (∃x)c(x)$ as well as to: $(∀y)b(y)∧(∃y)c(y)$.

In turn, the above formulas are also equivalent to: $(∀x)(∃y)[b(x)∧c(y)]$ (see [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction)).

The case of: $(∀x)(∃x)(b(x) ∧ c(x))$ is different.

This formula is equivalent to $(∃x)(b(x) ∧ c(x))$; adding a new quantifier $∀x$ to a formula that has no variable $x$ free does not change the meaning of the formula.